# after converting txt(mixed numbers and characters) to SQL - defining between numbers and words

Tags: java, sql

i want to create DB from the content of Subtitles files.
The result from importing srt file (converted to txt) is a long column of numbers, seconds - depicted by numbers - and the subtitle itself all mixed together.

[image: Exemple]

I want to rearrange it into three columns - the increment numbers as Primary key, time of subtitles and the subtitles - all of those in one row, so I would be able to check when a word has been used on the movie and to return the time in the movie .

sorry if its not uttered articulatly, It was hard to depict.\

thank you all!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your input rows in order. You need variables for the three fields in the new database table. Whenever you meet a number, you know a new group begins. Save any old group to your new database table, clear your values except set the new primary key to the number you just got. When you meet something that is not a number, if you already have a time in your current group, you know the new item is a line of the subtitle. In this case, append it to the susbtitle unless it’s blank. If you had not already got a time, you have now, assign it as such. Remember after your loop ends to save the last group to the database.